# How to add active class on Bootstrap list item and remove active from others?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have following HTML code:

```
<a href="" ng-ctrl="ThemesCtrl" ng-click="checkThemeContent(theme)" ng-repeat="theme in themes" ng-hide="theme[filterProp] !== filterValue" class="list-group-item ng-scope">
    <b class="ng-binding">Test</b>
    <span class="themesListIcons ng-binding">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> 0
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 2
    </span>
</a>
```

And I would like to after click add active class to item selected item and remove active class from all others items in list.

I tried to do this by this way:

```
// Set active list item
$('a.list-group-item').click(function() {
    alert('test');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

But it does not working.

Could somebody tell me how can I do it in right way?

Using AngularJS or jQuery.

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/06qxp3x2/ - can you show full html of your list?

Comment: have a look at `ng-class` and `ng-click` in the angular doc

Comment: Are you looking for something like - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/dg4rpadr/

Answer (score 2):

This might too late but someone else will find this useful. In your jQuery code you are adding "active" class to the parent.

Using Bootstrap and jQuery you have to use the following code.

**Bootstrap (Div Structure):**

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Item 1
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Item 2
    </a>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
jQuery("a.list-group-item").click(function (e) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
 // Set active list item 
 $('a.list-group-item').click(function() {
    alert('test');

    $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');

    // or 

    $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');

    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
 });
```

You have to find active element, remove 'active' class and only then add it to the new item.
Currently you are setting  active class on new element, and later removing it from everyone.

Edit:
Just noticed angular tag..
You should definitely use ng-class attribute and avoid declaring your own click handlers where possible.

```
<a ... ng-class="{active:theme == currentTheme}" ng-click="checkThemeContent(theme);currentTheme=theme" ..>
```